# How can i echo only once inside a foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I was wondering how can I echo only once inside a PHP foreach loop? Here is my code:

```
foreach(range(1, $numDays) as $number):
    $counter++;
    echo $number;

    if($counter < 8){
        //echo only once bellow
        echo "<div>header</div>";
        //echo only once above          

        echo "hello";

        //echo only once below
        echo "<div>footer</div>";
        //echo only once above          
    }   
endforeach;
```

Basically whats inside the "//echo only once" is what I want to echo only once while the the loop is less than the number 8. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a `break` statement...?

Comment: if you want to echo it once, then take it out of the loop, put the header above before foreach, put the footer below after the loop

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly, why not pull the pieces you don't need iterated outside of the loop?

```
//echo only once bellow
    echo "<div>header</div>";
//echo only once above           

foreach(range(1, $numDays) as $number):
    $counter++;
    echo $number;
    if($counter < 8){
        echo "hello";
    } 
endforeach;

//echo only once below
    echo "<div>footer</div>";
//echo only once above
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right, u wish to echo header and footer only once 
 use a flag variable for it

```
foreach(range(1, $numDays) as $number):
      $counter++;
      echo $number;
      $flag=1;

      if($counter < 8){
           //echo only once bellow
           if($flag == 1)
                 echo "<div>header</div>";
           //echo only once above           


           echo "hello";


           //echo only once below
           if($flag == 1)
           {
                echo "<div>footer</div>";
               // Since you are done printing change the flag back to '0'
               $flag = 0;
           }
           //echo only once above           
      } 
  endforeach;
```